# How to prevent attaching event handler multiple times?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have a function, that will attach `click` event handler to my element:

```
function attachClickToElem() {
    $('.elem').on('click', function () {
        alert('Hello World');
    });
}
```

The problem is that whenever I call this function,
n `click` handler attach to my element, so when 
I call it twice, I get two `alert` when I click on my element:

```
$(function () {
    attachClickToElem();
    attachClickToElem();
});
```

How can I prevent it? And check if my element 
has already `click` handler?

**[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxbDv/)**

Comment: Why not just unbind before you bind every time.... saves on memory leak then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxbDv/1/)**

Use `.each()` method to loop through your elements,
and check a **flag** for already event handlers with
`.data()` method, if the flag is `true`, skip the current loop.
Otherwise, attach the event handler to element
and set the flag as `true`.

```
function attachClickToElem() {
    $('.elem').each(function () {
        var $elem = $(this);

        // check if event handler already exists
        // if exists, skip this item and go to next item
        if ($elem.data('click-init')) {
            return true;
        }

        // flag item to prevent attaching handler again
        $elem.data('click-init', true);

        $elem.on('click', function () {
            alert('Hello World');
        });
    });
}
```

---

References:

- [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 15):

Try

```
function attachClickToElem() {
    $('.elem').off('click.mytest').on('click.mytest', function () {
        alert('Hello World');
    });
}

$(function () {
    attachClickToElem();
    attachClickToElem();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tU85P/)

Another way

```
function attachClickToElem() {
    $('.elem').filter(function(){
        return !$(this).data('myclick-handler');
    }).on('click.mytest', function () {
        alert('Hello World');
    }).data('myclick-handler', true);
}

$(function () {
    attachClickToElem();
    attachClickToElem();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tU85P/2/)

Comment: I like the first solution with an event namespace: clean and simple

Comment: When would you recommend the use of the second solution with a filter? Is the off/on cycle expensive?

Comment: @xtian I will recommend the first one, but to handle dynamic element you should really use delegated events

Answer (score 2):

Something close to this I believe:

```
function attachClickToElem() {
    $('.elem:not(.has-click-handler)')
        .addClass('has-click-handler')
        .on('click', function () {
          alert('Hello World');
    });
}
```